# elements in aframe are outside the aframe circle and become invisible depending on z coordinate

Tags: 3d, move, drag, aframe

I am new to A-Frame,
I want to allow a user to change the position of an element in the A-Frame environment so on click of the element on "dragend" I am calculating the new x y and z using the old ones plus the offset 
it works good, however when z is too big, its new position is outside the A-Frame circle and become invisible for the user.
I tried to calculate z depending on x and y coordinate, also it does not work 
how x,y and z should be calculated correctly to prevent the element of being disappeared???

Comment: what do you mean by "aframe circle" ?

Comment: i meant the element is invisible when I open the aframe inspecter i can see the environment as a sphere and i can see the hidden elements